# adding pods to compile sources (iOS App)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

in our last sprint we tried to add some cocoapods to the project.

Unfortunately, the pods are not added automatically to the compile sources in the base project in Xcode.

That means that I needed to copy some relevant .m files to the list.

Well, it worked just fine for one pod.. But now I'm trying to add ShakeKit Pod and it's just not right! Plus, I don't see the benefits of using cocoapods if I need to import every .m file to my project.

Anyone here knows to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Environment Details:**

- iOS SDK - 8.3
- Xcode - 6.3

Comment: You should not need to add any thing to you complied source. CocoaPods will create a separate project which will contain all the pods used. This project will be compelled to a library/framework which is linked to you main project. Make sure you open the workspace and not just you main project file.

Comment: Like rckoenes said, no need to add the .m files manually. Remove your manually added .m files, and close your project. Run pod install and start the workspace, not your currently closed project file

Answer (score 0):

I've found that $(inherited) was missing from my Other Linker Flags build setting. Applying this option fixed a missing library issue I was seeing.

Just like the guy from this thread :

[Error: ld: library not found for -lPods with CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods)