# How do I fix the directory not found for option -F error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm receiving the following error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

How do I fix this without removing the framework search path? I need the framework search path for my AdMob framework.

Comment: Try the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods. Double click on your `Framework Search Paths` and add what is included in their to your question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I fixed it! Since my project is migrated from a previous version of Xcode, I had to clear the value in Framework Search Path, which is in Build Settings under Search Paths.

The old value was something like `$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/MyProject` and I simply deleted it.

Comment: For me the old value was `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks $(inherited)`. Removing it eliminated the warning. Thanks!