# Xcode 8 - directory not found for option '-F'

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Started a new project in Xcode 8 beta 5, and I'm getting a warning for each cocoa pod in each of my targets:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/NinjaCoder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NinjaProduct-bfwyaspiuhsjzkhepkjmeoiayjnk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PureLayout'
```

I can still run, but I'd like to get rid of these warnings. Tried the solutions at this link, but they did not work: [How do I fix the directory not found for option -F error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676490/how-do-i-fix-the-directory-not-found-for-option-f-error)