# Xcode 6 clang error after checkout from SVN

Tags: ios, xcode6, clang, cocoapods

Recently I export my ios project to svn. After checkout from svn I got the following error:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
here is the screenshot[image]

I tried the following:
1.clean & build
2.Creating new schema
3. Build Phases" -> "Compile Sources" and look for duplicate of classes.
4. removing derived data.
none of these works. Also tried almost everything I found in stackoverflow. But nothing works for me. I've several pods framework installed. I doubt if those are causing the problem. Any suggestion??

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Build Settings" -> Library Search Path.
and see whether the desired lib file is present on the path which is mentioned there.

Also check the Header Search Path also.

Hope this helps!