# Firebase cocoa pod installation show error lGoogleToolboxForMac missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have tried to add firebase sdk using pods, but when I run the project I am getting the error framework not found. What can I do to solve this issue?

Error : Library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac 
Also  pods -> products libGoogleToolboxForMac.a is showing red

Comment: Have you tried deleting this red entry "libGoogleToolboxForMac.a" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: ld: library not found for -lPods with CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489920/error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods-with-cocoapods)

Comment: After you added pods, do you open the project with .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace?

Comment: i'm also walking with .xcworkspace and i'm not able to delete red entry  "libGoogleToolboxForMac.a"

Answer (score 0):

pod ‘Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
pod ‘GoogleSignIn’

I was getting the same error but after adding above pods I am not getting it.

and also check if your firebase.plist is correctly put.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem after integrating firebase pods in my project and i have solved this issue by updating pods in terminal. Try it may be it can also help you out.