XCode workspace ".xcworkspace" generated with "pod install" does not build
I created a sample QT app, opened its CMakeLists.txt in QT Creator, selected iOS Simulator configuration and run CMake. It generated XCode project at build/Qt_6_7_0_iOS_Release_Simulator/AdExample.xcodeproj/.
After that I created Podfile in build/Qt_6_7_0_iOS_Release_Simulator directory with the following content:
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '14.0'

target 'AdExample' do
  pod 'YandexMobileAdsMediation', '7.5.1'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end

Where YandexMobileAdsMediation is an Advertising Framework that I am trying to use in my QT app, see their docs.
Then I run
pod install

command from the command line, opened generated AdExample.xcworkspace in XCode and tried to build, but got the following error:
ld: library 'Pods-AdExample' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What does it mean? Where should I add -v option?
Below I provide full XCode screenshot just in case:

What can be wrong with libPods-AdExample.a?
Their example that I successfully built also have a similar .a:

and it exists in the project build folder along with other .a files:
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VGSLNetworking/libVGSLNetworking.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaHostState/libAppMetricaHostState.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaStorageUtils/libAppMetricaStorageUtils.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VGSLFundamentals/libVGSLFundamentals.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DivKit/libDivKit.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DivKit_LayoutKitInterface/libDivKit_LayoutKitInterface.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaProtobufUtils/libAppMetricaProtobufUtils.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaCoreExtension/libAppMetricaCoreExtension.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaProtobuf/libAppMetricaProtobuf.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/libGoogle-Mobile-Ads-SDK.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaEncodingUtils/libAppMetricaEncodingUtils.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaFMDB/libAppMetricaFMDB.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KSCrash/libKSCrash.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VGSLUI/libVGSLUI.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaCore/libAppMetricaCore.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-YandexMobileAdsExample.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DivKit_LayoutKit/libDivKit_LayoutKit.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaCrashes/libAppMetricaCrashes.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaLog/libAppMetricaLog.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaNetwork/libAppMetricaNetwork.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade/libDivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DivKit_Serialization/libDivKit_Serialization.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaCoreUtils/libAppMetricaCoreUtils.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppMetricaPlatform/libAppMetricaPlatform.a
./Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VGSL/libVGSL.a

Also libPods-AdExample.a exists in AdExample build directory along with other .a files:
./VGSLNetworking/libVGSLNetworking.a
./AppMetricaHostState/libAppMetricaHostState.a
./AppMetricaStorageUtils/libAppMetricaStorageUtils.a
./VGSLFundamentals/libVGSLFundamentals.a
./DivKit/libDivKit.a
./DivKit_LayoutKitInterface/libDivKit_LayoutKitInterface.a
./AppMetricaProtobufUtils/libAppMetricaProtobufUtils.a
./AppMetricaCoreExtension/libAppMetricaCoreExtension.a
./AppMetricaProtobuf/libAppMetricaProtobuf.a
./Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/libGoogle-Mobile-Ads-SDK.a
./AppMetricaEncodingUtils/libAppMetricaEncodingUtils.a
./AppMetricaFMDB/libAppMetricaFMDB.a
./KSCrash/libKSCrash.a
./VGSLUI/libVGSLUI.a
./AppMetricaCore/libAppMetricaCore.a
./DivKit_LayoutKit/libDivKit_LayoutKit.a
./AppMetricaCrashes/libAppMetricaCrashes.a
./AppMetricaLog/libAppMetricaLog.a
./AppMetricaNetwork/libAppMetricaNetwork.a
./DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade/libDivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade.a
./libPods-AdExample.a
./DivKit_Serialization/libDivKit_Serialization.a
./AppMetricaCoreUtils/libAppMetricaCoreUtils.a
./AppMetricaPlatform/libAppMetricaPlatform.a
./VGSL/libVGSL.a

but it is not clear why is not it found. libPods-YandexMobileAdsExample and libPods-AdExample are specified in the same sections in their .pbxproj files.
pod install command output:
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppLovinSDK (12.6.1)
Installing AppLovinYandexMobileAdsAdapters (12.6.1.2)
Installing AppMetricaCore (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaCoreExtension (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaCoreUtils (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaCrashes (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaEncodingUtils (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaFMDB (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaHostState (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaLog (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaNetwork (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaPlatform (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaProtobuf (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaProtobufUtils (5.8.0)
Installing AppMetricaStorageUtils (5.8.0)
Installing BigoADS (4.2.3)
Installing BigoADSYandexMobileAdsAdapters (4.2.3.9)
Installing ChartboostSDK (9.7.0)
Installing ChartboostYandexMobileAdsAdapters (9.7.0.12)
Installing DivKit (30.18.0)
Installing DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade (4.4.0)
Installing DivKit_LayoutKit (30.18.0)
Installing DivKit_LayoutKitInterface (30.18.0)
Installing DivKit_Serialization (30.18.0)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (11.7.0)
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (2.6.0)
Installing GoogleYandexMobileAdsAdapters (11.7.0.3)
Installing InMobiSDK (10.7.5)
Installing InMobiYandexMobileAdsAdapters (10.7.5.2)
Installing IronSourceSDK (8.3.0.0)
Installing IronSourceYandexMobileAdsAdapters (8.3.0.2)
Installing KSCrash (2.0.0-rc.2)
Installing MintegralAdSDK (7.6.9)
Installing MintegralYandexMobileAdsAdapters (7.6.9.3)
Installing MyTargetYandexMobileAdsAdapters (5.21.7.2)
Installing StartAppSDK (4.10.4)
Installing StartAppYandexMobileAdsAdapters (4.10.4.3)
Installing UnityAds (4.12.3)
Installing UnityAdsYandexMobileAdsAdapters (4.12.2.3)
Installing VGSL (6.5.0)
Installing VGSLFundamentals (6.5.0)
Installing VGSLNetworking (6.5.0)
Installing VGSLUI (6.5.0)
Installing VungleAds (7.4.1)
Installing VungleYandexMobileAdsAdapters (7.4.1.1)
Installing YandexMobileAds (7.5.1)
Installing YandexMobileAdsMediation (7.5.1)
Installing myTargetSDK (5.21.8)
Installing myTrackerSDK (3.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `AdExample.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 49 total pods installed.

[!] [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"buildSettings"=>{}, "buildStyles"=>["46E0D197708B4914B8435B77", "4F86475E04594C3090266BEB", "4699D34445A045B588C7F609", "9F302499CF354E9F8FE01881"]} for the 'PBXProject' isa.
If this attribute was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade (4.4.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade (4.4.0)


Probably helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724469/2394762

I was able to fix the build by adding ${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR} to LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS in AdExample.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj:
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(inherited)",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaCore\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaCoreExtension\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaCoreUtils\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaCrashes\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaEncodingUtils\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaFMDB\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaHostState\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaLog\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaNetwork\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaPlatform\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaProtobuf\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaProtobufUtils\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AppMetricaStorageUtils\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DivKit\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DivKitBinaryCompatibilityFacade\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DivKit_LayoutKit\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DivKit_LayoutKitInterface\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DivKit_Serialization\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/KSCrash\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VGSL\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VGSLFundamentals\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VGSLNetworking\"",
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/VGSLUI\"",
    "\"${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/usr/lib/swift/${PLATFORM_NAME}\"",
    /usr/lib/swift,
    "\"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}\"",
);

but it is not clear why pod install command does not add this path.
XCode screenshot:

